# Translator Text API endpoint returning 404 code with message "Resource not found" as a JSON Object

Tags: azure

After creating a service for Text Translator of Azure service, the end point when tried with the one of the keys provided returns a json object with 404 error code and Message "Resource not found"

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "404",
        "message": "Resource not found"
    }
}
```

**Postman Parameters used are:**

**URL:**
https://agro.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=ta,en

**Body JSON:**

```
{
    [
        "Text" : "Hello World"
    ]
}
```

With **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** parameter in header, is that which was given as the subscription key for cognitive service of Azure when registering.

NOTE: HTTP POST Method used.

Please suggest a solution to resolve the problem and THANK YOU for this.

**Screenshot Shared below as link:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWhs8.png)

Comment: Please provide sample Postman / any language code sample with your Key redacted / removed.

Comment: Yes wilco @SanketTarunShah, please check on the above question edit, thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Microsoft docs, your endpoint seems to be invalid. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translate?pivots=programming-language-javascript

HTTP POST Endpoint: `https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/?api-version=3.0&to=ta,en`

```
    headers: {
      'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-ClientTraceId': uuidv4().toString()
    }
```

Body:

```
    body: [{
          'text': 'Hello World!'
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @SanketTarunShah, But the URL in question posted above is the same as that provided in end point form the Microsoft Azure registration, when I used the answered URL or generic URL from link to get Central Asian Service along with key, it responded with below message:

`{"error":{"code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}`

Please verify!

Comment: I confirm, you should not use the enpoint provide by azure portal. But the one from the document is working. The endpoint of the azure portal can be used if you enable Virtual Network support (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/Translator/reference/v3-0-reference). And you must also make sure to secify the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region header in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL correct for the Global endpoint (i.e. `api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com`), but not for the "custom" endpoint like `{your_translator_name}.cognitiveservices.azure.com`. In that case you need to add `/translator/text/v3.0` after the host name, so the full URL should be either 
`https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=ta,en`

or
`https://agro.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/v3.0/translate?api-version=3.0&to=ta,en`

Unfortunately, is isn't stated clearly that we have to use different routes for accessing the Azure Translator service globally or via a Virtual Network in the documentation, I noticed this only by looking at the sample API call at the end of the section [Translator v3.0 - Virtual Network support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#virtual-network-support)